# Awk : does not report error for 202D, 203B etc, it accepts one alpha character

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I need to find out whether a field in a pipe delimited file is a numeric or not.
I need to report if the field is not a numeric field, ignore if it is numeric 
and also ignore if it is null.
I have other computations.

I wrote this code:

```
gawk -v w_column_pos="$column_pos" -F "|" '
$w_column_pos !~ /^([+-]|[0-9])[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)$|^([+-]|[0-9])[0-9]*$|^$/ { print $w_column_pos," is not Numeric"; } ' $src_data_file
```

`w_column_pos="$column_pos"` is used for getting the column number

The problem is, it does not report error for `202D`, `203B` etc; it accepts one alpha character.

But it does report error for `202DD`.

I previously had `/^([+-]|[0-9])[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?$|^$/`; this also had the same issue.

```
Sample input file
Name|Designation|Is Employee| Organisation ID|Hire Date
Alex Conolly|Prof1|TrUE|100|12072015
Thomas |Prof2|TRUE|200B|09072016
Christine prof1|FALSE||24902007
John Martini|PPP|TRUE~FALSE|202|11782099
xxYY |PPP|TRUE|91.67|11782099
ABD S | XXX | FALSEx | 209|11093000

I am asking about 4th column: Organisation id which is a number type

My code works fine, but 200B(in the 3rd row) is not reported
```

Comment: it would be a good idea to give a sample input text and expected output as well

Comment: You can probably simplify your example to something along the lines of `awk 'BEGIN { print "202D" ~ /pattern/ }'` - that would make it easier for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: added the sample input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the pattern to:

```
/^([+-]|[0-9])[0-9]*([.][0-9]*)$|^([+-]|[0-9])[0-9]*$|^$/
```

The unprotected "." was matching the "B".